# What library to import for #import <libxml/HTMLparser.h>

Tags: iphone, xcode, asihttprequest

I have imported `ASIHTTP files` into my project and inside  `ASIWebPageRequest.m` there is the following import:

```
#import <libxml/HTMLparser.h>
```

which is not recognized. What library should I add in order to be recognized?

Comment: libxml2 is that you need

Comment: I have added libxml2.dylib and is still not working

Comment: Because it's an include directory, not the dynamic library what you need. Add the <sysroot>/usr/include/libxml2 directory to the include paths (-I)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Go to the Project build settings (Project->Edit Project Settings->Build) and find the "Search Paths". In "Header Search Paths" add the following path:

> $(SDKROOT)/usr/include/libxml2

Note, you may be missing all development headers after upgrading OS X (at least this was the case for me with Mavericks). To reinstall the command line tools run:

> xcode-select --install

Answer (score 10):

With xcode 4.5, it doesn't work. I try with 
    /usr/include/libxml2
and it works well

Answer (score 1):

putting `${SDK_DIR}/usr/include/libxml2` for the "Header Search Paths" build setting worked for me.

*Info: I'm using xcode 5